# input() not being recognized by other module from main in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, python-import, program-entry-point

I have two scripts one that is main.py which is being ran through the terminal and takes in input(). And script1.py that basically takes in the file and parses through it.

I have been getting errors because of importing of script1.py that is saying variable not defined. 
Error:

````
File "/Users/jeremy/Desktop/folder1/script1.py", line 5, in <module>
    open_document= open(document_path)
NameError: name 'document_path' is not defined```
````

main.py:

```
import sys
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd
from maybe import start_maybe 
from script1 import start_s1

document_path = input("What is the file path? ")

open_document = open(document_path) #filelocation 
good = input("What is/are the good numbers? ")
bad = input("What is/are the bad numbers? ")
function1 = start_s1(good,bad)
print ("FQDN document created!")
maybeasn = start_maybe(good,bad)
print("Directory created for manual review, file is located inside")
```

This is script1.py:

```
import os
import csv
import re
import main.document_path

open_document= open(document_path)

file_name = (os.path.basename(document_path))
def start_s1(good, bad):
    with open ((('fqdn_') +(str(file_name).rstrip('.csv'))) , 'w') as output:
        with open_document as file:
            fqdn_data = csv.writer(output)
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            good_nums = good
            bad_nums = bad
            maybe_nums = []
            for row in reader:
                if row[3] in good_nums:
                    fqdn_data.writerow([row[2]])
```

What am I doing wrong and what would be the fix so that script1.py can understand what my variable `document_path` is from main.py

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you modify script1.py ?

Comment: Within python you only import modules or functions/classes from modules.  You cant import a variable from a different module. ```import main.document_path```, ill put an answer to this with revised code

Comment: Maybe you could try to do the import after the variable assigment

Comment: @tomgalpin You can import variables from other modules without any issues. He would just need to change his import to `from main import document_path`

Comment: No this is still incorrect.. If structures properly it would work but as it is above, youll have a loop in your imports.  If you try and import anything from main in script1 youll be executing main again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment, you should restructure your code and pass  the documentpath variable between your modules/functions.

main.py

```py
import sys
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd
from maybe import start_maybe 
from script1 import start_s1

document_path = input("What is the file path? ")

good = input("What is/are the good numbers? ")
bad = input("What is/are the bad numbers? ")
function1 = start_s1(document_path,good,bad)
print ("FQDN document created!")
maybeasn = start_maybe(good,bad)
print("Directory created for manual review, file is located inside")
```

script1.py:

```py
import os
import csv
import re


def start_s1(document_path,good, bad):
    open_document= open(document_path)

    file_name = (os.path.basename(document_path))
    with open ((('fqdn_') +(str(file_name).rstrip('.csv'))) , 'w') as output:
        with open_document as file:
            fqdn_data = csv.writer(output)
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            good_nums = good
            bad_nums = bad
            maybe_nums = []
            for row in reader:
                if row[3] in good_nums:
                    fqdn_data.writerow([row[2]])
```

Comment: Just what i was about to recomend. However dont you need to change the parameters of `start_s1` so it takes `document_path` as the first parameter

Comment: @tomgalpin thanks for the help and explanation. I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

While answer of @tomgalpin is good, you can also use that in your `scrip1.py`:

```py
import os
import csv
import re
import __main__.document_path

open_document= open(document_path)

file_name = (os.path.basename(document_path))
def start_s1(good, bad):
    with open ((('fqdn_') +(str(file_name).rstrip('.csv'))) , 'w') as output:
        with open_document as file:
            fqdn_data = csv.writer(output)
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            good_nums = good
            bad_nums = bad
            maybe_nums = []
            for row in reader:
                if row[3] in good_nums:
                    fqdn_data.writerow([row[2]])
```

and this in your `main.py` script:

```
import sys
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd
from maybe import start_maybe 

document_path = input("What is the file path? ")
from script1 import start_s1

open_document = open(document_path) #filelocation 
good = input("What is/are the good numbers? ")
bad = input("What is/are the bad numbers? ")
function1 = start_s1(good,bad)
print ("FQDN document created!")
maybeasn = start_maybe(good,bad)
print("Directory created for manual review, file is located inside")
```

The `__main__` module in `script.py` is one of the magics of Python.